# Why is it that everytime I mistype a command bash stops working?

Tags: bash, command-line, fedora, gnome-terminal, command-not-found

Every time I mistype a command such as `cd..` (e.g. I forgot to separate `cd`and `..` with a space) the command prompt disappears and I can no longer use commands in the terminal unless I close and reopen it:

```
[user@Host Downloads]$ cd..
bash: cd..: command not found...


cd ..
exit
q 
man                             
aaaaaa      
bash
```

Why does the command prompt stop working and how do I exit this state without restarting the terminal?

Comment: Does `Ctrl+C` do anything at that point? What happens if you first do `set -x`? (undo that change with `set +x` afterwards)

Comment: does anything come back from `declare -f command_not_found_handle`   ?

Comment: a long shot, but also `echo $PROMPT_COMMAND`

Comment: From another window, run `netstat -a -p | grep command-not-found`. What state is the connection in?

Comment: Thanks everyone. The first suggestion by @Kusalananda worked. I will keep all of your recommedations in mind if Ctrl+C doesn't bail me out next time. I'm glad I didn't loose my terminal session this time.

Comment: We might be able to fix it more permanently if you're interested in getting to the bottom of it...?

Comment: Could you please update the question with the output of the commands that people asks you to try (including my suggestion with `set -x`)?

Comment: Just to clarify: I **don't** consider pressing `Ctrl+C` when this happens a _solution_ to this issue.

Comment: As to why this is happening; there is a package called 'command-not-found' (that's its name in debian) that puts a hook into your shell and attempts to locate, download, and install commands whenever you type something that bash cannot find in the PATH.  It tends to be slow.  Disable it.

Comment: Related: [Why a long delay after command not found?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25681/why-a-long-delay-after-command-not-found)

Comment: @Jeff Schaller Why do you think this is a problem? I assumed it is something that is common with bash when someone types similar commands. If you try do the same in your terminal does the same problem happen to you. If the answer is no and it is not a characteristic of bash then I am interested in fixing it.

Comment: @Kusalananda I didn't need to try the rest of the outputs after your suggestion worked because I was in the middle of some work and setting and unsetting unknown variables might have broken something in that session. Why don't you consider the `Ctrl + C` trick a solution? If a browser window hangs you just do `Ctrl + X` isn't this similar?

Comment: It's not a solution, it's a band aid, since it doesn't stop it from happening again. It is not the way a shell should behave. See mattdm's answer, which is just a guess and a stab at possibly alleviating it. By helping us diagnose it, we might be able to solve it *properly*.

Comment: @Mark Plotnick thanks but my case wasn't a delay. It was the equivalent of an infinite loop. I've waited well over 10 minutes and it would never have returned without intervention.

Comment: I made a typo, it should be `Ctrl + W`

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia, no; when I type a command that isn't found, I get something like `-bash: cd..: command not found`, which is why *I* think we should get to the bottom of it. But what *you* want is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a feature enabled by default which attempts to search for uninstalled packages which might provide the command you typed. This should be very fast, but it seems like for some reason on your system, it is not.

There are several things one could do to diagnose that, but to just solve the immediate problem, you can disable that feature with

```
sudo dnf remove PackageKit-command-not-found
```

Comment: Oh I see so your telling me that behind the scenes this feature is still searching which might explain why I was still able to use the terminal instead of it just freezing, but in my case I waited probably over 10 minutes and the PS1 command prompt didn't return. Isn't this odd?

Comment: Yes, and yes, definitely odd. What does `pkcon refresh` do?