# Why does it take more time to identify an incorrect password than to identify a correct one?

Tags: linux, login, password

It takes almost two seconds before my linux machine replies the password is incorrect while the correct one gets accepted almost instantaneously.

Comment: See [Why is there a big delay after entering a wrong password](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2126/why-is-there-a-big-delay-after-entering-a-wrong-password)

Comment: That means I should probably delete this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, that's an intentional delay to prevent someone from being able to brute force a bunch of passwords in a short time.