# Remove delay after wrong sudo password entry on arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, login, pam

I have searched everywhere and what people say is that you have to give the `nodelay` argument to the `pam_unix.so` in `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` to remove delay. I tried doing that and it didn't work. I even added `nodelay` to every `pam_unix.so` in the `/etc/pam.d/` folder and it didn't work either. When that didn't work I tried adding this line: `auth optional pam_faildelay.so delay=0` in `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` and it didn't work either. On the other hand, if I set the delay to more than 3 seconds it adds the delay but below 3 seconds  it does not work. I am really confused and would appreciate if someone could answer me.

I also tried changing the FAIIL_DELAY to 0 in my `/etc/login.defs` and that also didn't work. Lastly, I looked for the `auth required pam_unix.so try_first_pass nullok` line in my `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` file but couldn't even find that line. The closest line that resembled that was this line: `auth [success=2 default=ignore] pam_unix.so try_first_pass nullok`. I then added the `nodelay` argument to that but it didn't work too.

Comment: [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2128/22222) suggests that PAM will enforce a minimum delay of 2 seconds, but [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/213668/22222) gives a slightly different `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` delay that could work. Can you try that and tell us how it goes? If it works, we can mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: I followed this answer's steps first by changing the FAIL_DELAY to 0 in my `/etc/login.defs` but that didn't change anything. I then looked for the `auth      required  pam_unix.so     try_first_pass nullok` line in my `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` but I didn't find that exact line. However I found another similar line that read `auth       [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so           try_first_pass nullok`. I then added the nodelay argument at the end of the line but that didn't work either.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include all this in case someone else can help more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through some experimentation I discovered how to remove the incorrect password delay on arch.

In `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`, add `nodelay` to `auth` lines that mention the `pam_faillock.so` or `pam_unix.so` PAM modules.

In other words:

```
auth       required                    pam_faillock.so      preauth nodelay                                                
auth       [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so          try_first_pass nullok nodelay                                  
-auth      [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_systemd_home.so                                                                 
auth       [default=die]               pam_faillock.so      authfail nodelay

...
```

Many answers suggest adding the `nodelay` option to `pam_unix`, but it looks like `pam_faillock` has [recently](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/releases/tag/v1.5.1) [acquired](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/pull/296/files) a `nodelay` option as well.

Comment: Thank you it FINALLY worked!

Comment: I'm not certain what I did wrong, but this prevented me from `sudo`ing - every password is now the incorrect password.  Where's my live USB...

Answer (score 0):

After some additional experimentation it seems that faillock has a config file where you can put `nodelay`.

This works for me on Arch linux:
adding `nodelay` to the line with `pam_unix.so` in `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`

```
auth       [success=1 default=bad]     pam_unix.so          try_first_pass nullok nodelay
```

and appending `nodelay` to `/etc/security/faillock.conf`, just adding `nodelay` at the end of the file works fine.

Here you can additionally set `deny` to a higher number.

Also check:

```
man pam_unix
man pam_faillock
```

For me it wasn't so much to remove the delay when cancelling `sudo` but moreso for logging in.
This also removes the delay for authentication.